# Unique Token Id on every login In Symfony 1.4 / Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I am using an older version of Symfony 1.4

And I am using the sfGuardDoctrine plugin for basic security.

I want to double check that this will do what I want and also if there may be a better way to accomplish what I am doing.

```
 // make sure that the key is not in the database on signin    
do {
    // generate new keys
    $key = $this->generateRandomKey();
    // make sure random key is not used
    $key_check = Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardUserProfile')->checkDuplicateKey($key);    
} while (count($key_check) < 1);
```

generate random key code

```
private function generateRandomKey($len = 20)
{
  return base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
}
```

The Doctrine Query to get Token Id's

```
 static public function checkDuplicateKey($key) 
{
    return Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('u.token_id')
        ->from('sfGuardUserProfile u')
        ->where('u.token_id = ?')
        ->fetchOne(array($key), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
}
```

This code executes whenever a user logs in.
My questions are
1) Will it give me a unique id for every user? and 2) Is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Thank you in advance